# Is the Fisher King from Doctor Who the same one Referenced by T.S. Eliot in "The Waste Land"

Tags: doctor-who

While preparing for a midterm exam in one of my classes, I was researching the Fisher King, referenced in T.S. Eliot's poem, *The Waste Land*. As I typed "Fisher King" in to Google, I saw a suggested search for "Fisher King Doctor Who." Since I am a Doctor Who fan, I decided to check it out.

Apparently, the Fisher King is from an episode titled *Before the Flood*. I looked at [this page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fisher_King) hoping to find some answers, but unfortunately, nothing was listed stating that it was a reference.

Could someone with more knowledge than I shed some light on the subject? For the record, I do not know very much about the revived Doctor Who series, as I am a fan of the old one, and have not seen any of the new ones yet because I am still working my way through the original.

Comment: Is the Fisher King referenced by The Waste Land the same one from Arthurian legend?

Comment: Or from C.S. Lewis' *That Hideous Strength*?

Comment: @OrangeDog My professor did not really go in to detail about the origins of the one reference in The Waste Land. I will ask him.

Comment: It sounds like this is the work that you're supposed to be doing. Then you can come write a really good answer to this question when you're finished :)

Comment: @MattGutting I have never read _That Hideous Strength_ so I am afraid I cannot answer that.

Comment: @OrangeDog I only need to know what his role is in the story. I do not need to know about his origins, but I am curious.

Comment: Is he perchance wounded, and must wait in an difficult-to-access location for someone to heal him?

Comment: @OrangeDog Eliot only references the Fisher King as a sort of tortured soul.

Comment: Then yes, it's probably all the same Arthurian Fisher King.

Comment: @OrangeDog I have asked my professor about the background of the Fisher King in the poem, and he stated that it has its roots in Arthurian legend. Therefore, it is the same Fisher King, just presented in a very different way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a long story short, the concept of a [Fisher King](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FisherKing) dates back to [Arthurian Legend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_King) and shows up in many different pieces of media, sometimes explicitly referenced by that name and sometimes by the concept that there is a tie between the ruler and the realm, whether it's about righteousness or health.

As per [the wiki article you linked](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fisher_King), the name of the character may refer to the concept of the Fisher King as impotent, needing rescue by the people he rules so that he can restore them.

> The Fisher King was a figure in Arthurian legend. Having been wounded, the legendary king waits for someone who is able to heal him to arrive. This is similar to the Doctor Who character who is waiting for someone from his people to come and save him.

Comment: Warning: TVTropes link

Comment: @OrangeDog What is wrong with TVTropes?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife